# Model.fetch after a model.set: unexpected behaviour or a bug?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a rest API which is able to produce objects keys with null value.
This null value are not showen in the model.attributes.

Here an example:

the server can produce `{id: 1, attr: "someValue"}` or `{id: 2, attr: null}`

Now If I run the following code all things are ok:

```
m = new MyModel({id: 1});
m.fetch();
m.get("attr"); // "bar";

m = new MyModel({id: 2});
m.fetch();
m.get("attr"); // undefined;
```

---

If I run the following I have a problem with the render function in the View.
To understand why, please look this code:

```
m = new MyModel({id: 1});
m.fetch({
    success: function () {
         m.get("attr"); // "bar";
    }
});

m = new MyModel({id: 2});
m.fetch({
    success: function () {
         m.get("attr"); // "bar"; // actually it should be undefined or null
    }
});
```

---

My questions are:
1) Why I get this behaviour?
2) How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the problem in the view? What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: The problem in the view is that the attr value will refer to the previous model instead to be empty.

Comment: What makes you think the `fetch` will have finished the AJAX before you `m.get('attr')`?

Comment: @muistooshort thanks for your comment, I update my answer accordingly. Anyway: 1) I run m.get("attr"); after 5 seconds; 2) if I make m.get("attr") in success function in fetch the result does not change.

Comment: Are you sure that the server is returning what you hunk it is?

Comment: Yes, because if I put in the model the `function parse` the condition `if(!resp.attr){ resp.attr = undefined}` it updates the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... I see what's going on... In the first example, you're setting var m to a new model instance. In the second example, you're not resetting m to a new model, just setting the id value - it's still the first model. That's why you're not seeing a change to "null."

Comment: @BrendanDelumpa among all the answers you are right. What do you suggest to fix this behaviour? Using the parse function in the model it works (`if(!resp.attr){ resp.attr = undefined}`) but I would like to avoid this because it is too hardcoded.

Comment: @BrendanDelumpa I think I should set a new model instance every time. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get back earlier, but yes, you have to create a new model instance for each model var.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `m.get("attr") = "bar";` do you mean `m.get("attr") == "bar";` (note the double-equals)?  If not, then that code doesn't do what you probably think it does.

In any case, the problem is most likely that the fetch() call hasn't completed yet when you examine the value. Which was noted in comments by "mu is too short" as I was typing this. :)

Comment: thanks, I correct the m.get("attr") = "bar"; about the `fetch() call hasn't completed yet`, the fetch() call is finished when I run m.get("attr");

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a timing issue. A Backbone [`fetch`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L321) basically goes like this:

1. Set up a `$.ajax` call to the server using `m.id` for the REST route.
2. The AJAX success handler pass the returned data through [`parse`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-parse) and then hand the result of that to [`set`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-set).

So a `fetch` is pretty much a delayed `set` and [`set`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L247) doesn't do anything special that would ignore a `null` attribute value. In your case, the `fetch` should be a `m.set({id: 2, attr: null})` with a time delay.

I think you're seeing this:

1. Call `m.fetch()` and an AJAX request is initiated.
2. You look at `m.get('attr')` and don't see the `null` you're expecting.
3. The AJAX request completes and changes `m.get('attr')` to `null`.

Add a `success` handler to your fetch:

```
m.fetch({ success: function(m) { ... });
```

and see what `m.get('attr')` is in there or bind an event handler to wait for `attr` to change:

```
m.on('change:attr', function(m, attr) { ... });
m.fetch();
```

and see what happens.